# prerequirement for lvreduce to shrink a lvm disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, fedora

I am trying to **shrink** my Fedora 20 **lvm** partition/disk (only one partition) with **lvreduce**. I have done that for my VirtualBox but this time it is for a external USB disk. I have backup my disk already. Before I go, I still have two questions not clear:

**1.** I have to do this with a LiveCD? or the target partition/disk should not be running for this shrinking purpose?

**2.** Any Linux LiveCD, Ubuntu or Fedora or ...,  will be fine for my target Fedora hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll need the filesystem unmounted, but you don't need to actually use a live CD. A live CD is just convenient when the filesystem is `/`. (I haven't tried this, but I believe you could  actually do it online if you didn't mind destroying the filesystem.)
2. Any should work, as long as it has new enough tools (and, I suppose theoretically maybe not too new). To be safe, using a version that matches the OS you're running is probably best, just in case.